# Solving 3n+1 in java

Tags: java, collatz

I am trying to solve 3n+1 problem in java. UVA shows runtime error for my code.I am trying to solve a problem for the first time and I can't figure out the problem. I tested it with the inputs given on the site and it works.Is it rejected because my code works slow? If so, how can it be optimised?

PFB my code

```
import java.util.*;

class solution {


public static int[] clength = new int[1000000];

public static long nextnum(long n)
{

    if(n%2==0)
    {
        return n/2;
    }
    else
        return 3*n+1;
}

public static long cyclelength(long n)
{

    if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;

    }
    if (n < 1000000 && clength[(int)n] != 0)
    {
        return clength[(int)n];

    }
    long length= (1+ cyclelength(nextnum(n)));
    if (n < 1000000)
        clength[(int)n] = (int) length;

    return length;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(in.hasNext())
    {
        int a=in.nextInt();
        int b=in.nextInt();
        int min=Math.min(a, b);
        int max=Math.max(a, b);
        int count=0;

        for(int n=min;n<=max;n++)
        {
            count=(int) Math.max(count,cyclelength(n));

        }
        System.out.println(a + " " + b +" " +count );
    }
}

}
```

Comment: The text of the error message produced would be relevant here, especially since "runtime error" can be used in two rather dissimilar senses.

Comment: Can you print the value of `n` in `cycleLength` ? You should not have to cast it down to an `int`. If it needs to be an `int` because it is always small enough to be the index of an array, then it should be an `int`. Otherwise, it should be a `long` and you should not use an array in your solution

Comment: I don't know if the compiler optimizes `n%2==0` to `n & 1 == 0` but you can try that also.

Answer (score 0):

Although the problem statement specifies that there are no known numbers among those up to some unspecified number much larger than 1,000,000 for which the given sequence fails to terminate, it doesn't talk about what any of their cycle lengths are.  I think you'll find that some numbers have very long cycle lengths indeed.

Although you appear to make good use of memoization to avoid redundant computations, structuring the computation recursively puts you at risk of overflowing the call stack, which probably requires a cycle length of only a few tens of thousands.  Also, method invocations are much more expensive than simple branching, so your recursive approach is likely to be slower than an iterative one, too.

Comment: What can be done for such large cycle lengths?I used the long data type to store my cycle length  with iterative approach. But I am still getting the runtime error

Comment: @JTN, as I said, it is the recursive nature of your solution that makes long cycle lengths a problem for it.  Any recursive algorithm can be rewritten as an iterative one, and in this case that's not even hard to do.